Fixing Header rows while writing a pivot dataframe to excel
I am pivoting a dataframe and then filtering it. And then I need to write it to excel. But when I write it out,

it is inserting a blank row between the header rows and the data rows
I want the header row names in one row not two rows. So, in the example below for the output to excel, I wan thte column names to be "Code", "Invoice" , Unit Price", "2022-12", 2023-12", 2024-01". I do not need the row with "amount" at the top.

Executable code is below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'JDate':["2022-01-31","2022-12-05","2023-11-10","2023-12-03","2024-01-16","2024-01-06"],
        # 'Month':[1,12,11,12,1,1],
        'Code':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy'],
        'Unit Price':[np.nan,200,None,56,75,65],
        'Quantity':[1500, 140000, 1400000, 455, 648, 759],
        'Amount':[100, 10000, 100000, 5, 48, 59],
        'Invoice':['soccer','basketball','baseball','football','baseball','ice hockey'],
        'energy':[100.,100,100,54,98,3],
        'Category':['alpha','bravo','kappa','alpha','bravo','bravo']
})

df["JDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["JDate"])

df["JYearMonth"] =  df['JDate'].dt.to_period('M')


index_to_use = ['Category','Code','Invoice','Unit Price']
values_to_use = ['Amount']
# columns_to_use = ['Year','Month']
columns_to_use = ['JYearMonth']


df2 = df.pivot_table(index=index_to_use,
                            values=values_to_use,
                            columns=columns_to_use)

# df3 = df2[df2['Category']=='alpha']

# since this is an index you just filter for it
# df3 = df2.loc[['alpha']]
df3 = df2.xs('alpha',level='Category')
df3 = df3.reset_index() #this prevents merging of rows


writer= pd.ExcelWriter(
        "t2test6.xlsx",
        engine='xlsxwriter'
    )


# df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2",index=True)
# df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2test",index=True)
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2filter",index=True)

writer.close()


Slice "Amount" before xs:
df3 = (df2['Amount'].xs('alpha',level='Category')
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )

Output:
         Code   Invoice  Unit Price  2022-12  2023-12  2024-01
0  John Smith  football        56.0      NaN      5.0      NaN

